# Convergent sequence confusion

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am having an issue understanding why the sequence $x_n$ such that $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2x_n +1}$, $x_1 = 1$ is convergent. 
After plugging numbers into the sequence we discovered that the sequence is increasing and we could not find a limit that would make it bounded and therefore not convergent. Any ideas?

Comment: A bounded monotonic function is convergent, it may be increasing but if it has a upper bound then it is convergent. You can find the upper bound from induction

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can prove by induction that (for example) $x_n\lt 4$ for all $n$.

The numerical evidence that the sequence is increasing is useful. But a *proof* should be given (again by induction) that the sequence is increasing.

Comment: I understand that the sequence is increasing but how do i show that it is bounded?

Comment: or is that what the induction proves

Comment: Induction step: Suppose that $a_k\lt 4$. Then $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2a_k+1}\lt \sqrt{(2)(4)+1}=3\lt 4$.

Answer (score 0):

You must use mathematical induction to prove that $a_{n+1}>a_{n}$.
It is obviously true for $n=1$
So, I will jump to the main part:
If we assume that its also true for $n=k \implies a_{k+1}>a_{k}$
Now, we have to prove that is true for $n=k+1$

If we assume,
$$a_{k+1}>a_{k}$$
$$2a_{k+1}+1>2a_{k}+1$$
$$\sqrt{2a_{k+1}+1}>\sqrt{2a_{k}+1}$$
$$\implies a_{k+2}>a_{k+1}$$
Therefore, since for the case $n=1$ the proposition is true and whenever $n=k$ holds, $n=k+1$ is true, then  $a_{n+1}>a_{n}$ by PMI. This is basically saying that the sequence is increasing.

But, we know that $$a_{k+1}>a_{k}$$
$$\implies a_{k}<a_{k+1}=\sqrt{2a_{k}+1}$$
$$\iff a^2_{k}<2a_k+1$$
$$a^2_{k}-2a_k+1<2$$
$$(a_k-1)^2<2$$
$$\implies a_k<\sqrt{2}+1$$

Hence, our sequence is upper bounded and increasing, therefore by the monotonic convergence theorem the sequence is convergent.

---

Notice that we could have done it the way Andre Nicholas suggested but if the question asked for the limit of the sequence, do not mistake the upper-bound for the limit. In my case, the upper-bound is the limit. This can be proven as such:

$$\text{Assume} \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L \text{}$$
We can only do this because we proved earlier that there exists a limit. You can't assume there is a limit and find the limit and therefore say there is a limit.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{2a_n+1}=\sqrt{2L+1}$$
But, we know that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}=L$$
$$\implies \sqrt{2L+1}=L$$
The solution for L is $\sqrt{2}+1$ not $\sqrt{2}-1$ because it is an increasing sequence.